# Is a transit visa required to pass through Bangkok Airport?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, standard-visitor-visas, thailand

I have a flight from Bangalore, India to Manila, Philippines via Bangkok. It’s with the same airline (Thai Airways) but I will have to spend 10 hours in the airport at Bangkok for the connecting flight to Manila. Do I need a transit visa for Bangkok? Also, do I have to pass through immigration with luggage at Bangkok? I don’t have a visa for the Philippines as I will be staying there for a week. I have an Indian passport and a UK standard visit visa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you stay airside, you don't a transit visa. TG will check your luggage all the way to Manila. It will be a long wait, though.

As a frequent traveler to Bangkok, may I give you a small piece of advice that will make your transit smoother? Thai people are generally very friendly, if slow, but at the airport very much less friendly, and even slower. If you require assistance from TG staff or other, be extremely polite, and patient. They tend to get snarky and unhelpful, especially with people from the Indian subcontinent. I have witnessed this numerous times, including again last week.

Smile, wait in line, and say please