# Can Indian citizens get a transit visa on arrival at Don Mueang airport, Bangkok?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, thailand, dmk

I am an Indian, going to India from Philippines.
My flights are below

> Manila (MNL) TO Don Mueang (DMK) ( AIRASIA ZEST)
>
> Don Mueang (DMK) To Netaji Subhas Chandra Bose International Airport, Kolkatta (CCU) (THAI AIRASIA)

My transit time in Don Mueang (DMK) is 3 hrs 25 min.

- Can I get transit visa or Visa on arrival?
- How much time will take to get visa?
- Is this free for Indian passport holders?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE! Please use descriptive titles for your questions! I've now edited your question for you 

Comment: Does this help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119766/is-a-transit-visa-required-to-pass-through-bangkok-airport?rq=1 ?

Comment: Please state the airport name, not just the code.

Comment: Adding at the country name that you need the visa for also usefull (Bangkok, Thailand).

Comment: Do you have any check-in baggage?